Thymeleaf syntax for the form action
I have this form:
<body>
<h1>Fill out the form</h1>
<form action="@{/submit}" method="post" th:object="${person}">
    <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}" class="error"></span>

    <label for="name">Person Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" th:field="*{name}" />
    <br />

    <label for="orgName">Organization:</label>
    <input type="text" id="orgName" th:field="*{orgName}" />
    <br />

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}" />
    <br />

    <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label>
    <input type="tel" id="telephone" th:field="*{phone}" />
    <br />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>

but I see this on the browser:


You need to use th:action tag instead of action tag. And also specify the th namespace in html tag.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Fill out the form</h1>
    <form th:action="@{/submit}" method="post" th:object="${person}">
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}" class="error"></span>
    
        <label for="name">Person Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" th:field="*{name}" />
        <br />
    
        <label for="orgName">Organization:</label>
        <input type="text" id="orgName" th:field="*{orgName}" />
        <br />
    
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}" />
        <br />
    
        <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="telephone" th:field="*{phone}" />
        <br />
    
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

Checkout Details on Thymeleaf Form
